# How to create an php page with xslt?

Tags: php, html, xslt

I'm trying to make something with XSLT but i do not figure out on the web how to do it... My purpose was to create an html and a php page with my xsl applied to a XML schema . Is there a way to complete that task ? If yes, how ? Thanks

P.S.:
My XSL page already makes my html page but i want at the same time makes a php page, is there any way how to do it ?(is there a function to make an other page and make a php page ? )

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="xs:schema">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <center>
                <form action="add.php" method="post">
                    <table>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="xs:simpleType"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="xs:element[matches(@name,'supervision$')]/xs:complexType"/>
                        <xsl:result-document>

                        </xsl:result-document>
                    </table>
                </form>
            </center>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can create multiple documents with XSLT using the following XSLT 2.0 command [`<xsl:result-document`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document):

```
<xsl:result-document href="add.php" method="html">
     <html>
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="php">echo 'Hello World';</xsl:processing-instruction>
     </html>
 </xsl:result-document>
```

This will create the `add.php` with following content:

```
<html><?php echo 'Hello World';></html>
```

You can have a look at many examples and how-to create multiple documents with xslt:
http://www.cch.kcl.ac.uk/legacy/teaching/7aavdh06/xslt/html/module_09.html

Comment: <xsl:result-document href="add.php" method="php">
</xsl:result-document>
the problem is , xslt doesnt compute php page

Comment: use `method="xml"`, because a PHP or HTML is a xml file.

Comment: to be able to create <?php ?> output use `xsl:processing-instruction name="php"` see my edited answer.

Comment: and if i want to process more php code but in others template that i have?
i tried to use the result-document in others templates , but it's giving me an error "
Severity: fatal
Description: XTDE1490: Cannot write more than one result document to the same URI:"

Comment: Make ONE result-document for each file. When you start a new document, all content must be created inside that. You cannot start result-document multiple times for the same filename.

Comment: and if i want to append more information on that file ? How am i able to do it ?

Comment: no you cannot append to a file. Like I said, you need to build your XSLT wisely and then you don't have to append. Use the apply-templates, call-templates etc.